# Курсор в IntelliJ Idea 2016.1.3

Tags: intellij-idea, insert, курсор

Всем привет.

Mac OS El Captain
Intellij Idea 2016.1.3

Как поменять/переключить курсор в Intellij Idea 2016.1.3?
Не знаю как правильно это назвать, но суть в том, что курсор выглядит не вертикальной мигающей линией, а закрашенным мигающим участком. Как в Windows при нажатии Insert в Word. При этом символы не заменяются, а добавляются.
Перепробовал все комбинации, не могу понять - это глюк конкретно моей Intellij Idea 2016.1.3 или так и должно быть?! Хотя посмотрел на видео у других пользователей, курсор мигает вертикальной линией.
Прошу прощения за подобное изложение вопроса.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: это ведь даже не вопрос про идею. Insert глобальная клавиша =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**File** - **Setting** - **Appearance** - *Снять переключатель (галку)* **Use block caret**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5):

Tools - Vim Emulator ,снять галочку

Answer (score 2):

**FILE -> Settings -> Plugins -> IdeaVim** убрать галочки, или совсем снести пакость ;)

Answer (score 1):

Было тоже самое, включается и отключается этот режим клавишей **Insert (ins)**